# GeoServer raster issue

Tags: geoserver

I've been following [this](https://github.com/lcalisto/workshop-postgis-raster/blob/master/doc/geoserver.md) tutorial to server a very large raster tile set. The data set is many thousand 1km tiles covering the whole of London  (derived from LiDAR data) the data is stored on a PostgreSQL db the tiles are generated as the below command

`raster2pgsql -s 27700 -t 100x100 -I -C -M {}/raster_*_3d_{}.asc -F solar_rasters.solarp_3d_{} | psql -d lsom`

The error I receive when trying to add the store is

`Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:data/mosaicpgraster.pgraster.xml and hints Hints: REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@40290072 EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@14db3d9f[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] System defaults: FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = null COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl FEATURE_FACTORY = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@45394b31 LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true`

In the log I can see;

```
20 Nov 15:50:28 ERROR [jdbc.custom] - No level available for oek
20 Nov 15:50:28 ERROR [imagemosaic.jdbc] - No level available for oek
20 Nov 15:50:28 WARN [imagemosaic.jdbc] - java.io.IOException: No level available for oek
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: No level available for oek
```

`oek` is present in the connection xml as shown in the tutorial, but I'm not clear what this value should be.